# AngularJS $interval displays timer (when the interval will elapse)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi am new to Angular am using $interval to call a function periodically and i want to display a timer in the screen when the next function call will happen , a countdown to the next call . is there anyway simple way to do within this function .

```
function init(){
    $scope.interval = $interval(function(){
      $scope.loading = true;
    //$scope.countdown = countdown to next call;
      doSomework();
    }, 60000);
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome .Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd need to have the function to run each second and have it do the counting down. Have a `remainingSeconds` variable, set it to 60, run the countdown function each second, have it subtract the `remainingSeconds` variable by 1, once it is 0, do something.

Comment: I don't think i understand your comment , should i add an extra variable and intervalof initialise to the same time as the the interval '60000' and then do intervalof--  ?

Comment: I don't know Angular so I can't provide a code example, but if you change the interval to `1000` (one second) and then do the countdown in the function, that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need. The second argument in `$interval` is the time after which you want the function to execute and its in miliseconds so `1000ms=1sec`.
So after every second it will reduce thhe value of `$scope.remainingTimeby` 1. You can have the value according to your requirement. Just for demo i have considered it to be 60 and the interval to be 1sec so after every second the `$scope.remainingTimewill` be decremented by 1

```js
angular.module('timerApp', []);
angular.module('timerApp').controller('timerController', ['$scope', '$interval', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.remainingTime = 60;
  $scope.timeInterval=$interval(function(){
     $scope.remainingTime      =  $scope.remainingTime  - 1;
        if($scope.remainingTime==0){
           //$interval.cancel($scope.timeInterval);
           $scope.remainingTime=60;
        }
  }, 1000);
}]);
```

```html
<head>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="timerApp" ng-controller="timerController">
  
    <div >{{remainingTime}}</div>
</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: I use $interval to do polling the code above doesn't poll once the countdown is done it doesn't call again and rest time.Ideally i want to show time until next time i poll .

Comment: @Mero actually the interval is executing every second and we are decremening a variable b  ever second. So insead of cancelling he interval ou can reset it to original value. So it will start all over again. Updated the code.

Comment: thanks for you help , much appreciated . am still facing some issue but i will figure it out

Comment: if you can create a demo replicating the issue may i will be able to help figure out the issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
function init(){
   var remainingTime = 60;
   var interval   = $interval(function(){
   $scope.loading    = true;
   remainingTime     = remainingTime - 1;
   $scope.showRemainingTIme = remainingTime; // Use this variable to show on the view page
   if(remainingTime == 0) {
   $interval.cancel(interval);
    doSomework();
   }

  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I use $interval to do polling the code above doesn't poll once the countdown is done it doesn't call again and rest time.Ideally i want to display the remaining time until i will poll again